# jQuery click event doesn't work the second time

Tags: jquery, pagination

I'm using jQuery to handle and process Ajax pagination with Codeigniter .

When I load the page for the first time the Ajax works but when the page loaded and I click in the an other page link it doesn't work (it goes to the native URL).

This is my jQuery function:

```
function pagination(){
$('.paginate').click(function(){
   $('#loading').css('display','block');
   var b  = $(this).attr('href');
   b = b.split('/');
   b = 'http://'+'/'+b[2]+'/'+b[3]+'/indexAjax/'+b[5];
   grabpagination(b);
   return false;


});
}

function grabpagination(b){
    $.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url: b,
   cache: false,
   data: {},
   success: function (data) {
      $("#center").replaceWith("<div id='center'>"+data+"</div>");
        $('#loading').css('display','none');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 1100);

   },
   dataType: 'html'
});


}
```

and the HTML of the pagination UL

```
<ul id="pagination">
    <li class="current">1</li>
    <li><a class="paginate" href="http://under.dev/home/index/2">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="paginate" href="http://under.dev/home/index/4">3</a></li>
    <li class="text"><a class="paginate" href="http://under.dev/home/index/2">التالي</a></li>
    <li class="text"><a class="paginate" href="http://under.dev/home/index/14">الأخير</a></li>
</ul>
```

`under.dev` is just a virtual domain.

What's wrong? I'm using Firebug for debugging but it doesn't give any error.

---

**SOLVED Using `Live()` function.**

Comment: You have to recall the click function in the click callback so as to rearm the callback. Or do what is suggested in flesk's answer.

Comment: Done , i just read about live function , thank you a lot guys .

Comment: Maybe start by reading the official documentation that contains an example: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Do post ans if the problem gets solved ..it helps someone who come down to the page with no help !! cheers

Comment: Please, add your solution as an Answer instead of putting it in the Question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind events with the live() function if you want to bind to dynamically loaded data.

Comment: Done , i just read about live function , thank you a lot guys .