# Incrementally loading items from ajax using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can anyone help me with this little code? I'm trying to load a list of items when the page start, and then when a user click for more, more items will be loaded incrementally.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('videos.php', { id: "<?php echo $ID; ?>", start: 0 }, function(data) {
        $('#list').html(data);
    });
});

$('.showmorevids').click(function() {
    var $input = $('.showmorevids span').attr('id').split('-');
    alert(input);
    $.get('videos.php', { id: input[0], start: input[1], total: input[2] }, function(data) {
        $('#list').html(data);
        alert("success");
    });
});
```

The videos.php page will return a list of items and a new button with different id (id-start-total) so that I can use as new variable for the new request. The first $.get loaded just fine when the page load, but when the user click on the button for more, nothing happens, no request is sent. Can someone tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Use live('click') instead of click(). You can't bind to dynamically loaded content with click(). This is most likely a duplicate of [jQuery click event doesn't work the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947963/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-in-the-second-time/7947991#7947991)